# Confused about windows failover cluster, DC and SQL AlwaysOn

Tags: windows, windows-server-2012, cluster, failover

I'm setting up a AlwaysOn group for a SQL Server 2014 database.
However, as this is my first time I have a lot of questions and as I proceed to solve one issue, another arises and this seems to go forever.

So far I've managed to setup a server with Domain Controller, AD and DNS.
I've joined a another server as member of the Domain and everything works fine.

Now I'm setting up Failover cluster which is required in order to configure AlwaysOn group in SQL Server.

My confusion arises as I've read upon its not recommended to use the Domain Controller server as a member node in the Failover cluster. This means I need a another server. Atleast 3 servers?
I've also read that if it's going for production It's recommended to have a fourth as second Domain Controller?

All of a sudden it all ended in a lot of configuration and four servers and a lot of explaining to my boss :D

Is this true or am I wrong? Is there anything else I'll be needing until i reach my actual goal here?

Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the minimum number of machines recommended is 3. One DC, and 2 SQL servers. And in a production environment, you would never run just one DC. So that adds machine number 4.

If this was the only Windows based services you would ever run, then what I would do instead of 4 physical servers is 2 physical servers, and run a DC and a SQL server in separate Hyper-V VM's on each physical server.

Comment: Unfortunately the servers are VMWare so it doesn't works. Thanks for clearing it up!

Answer (score 2):

That sounds accurate.  You definitely don't want your domain controllers as cluster members.

Typically you would have more flexibility by adding virtuals as cluster members.  You still have the added cost of additional licenses, but it's a lot easier to spin up new servers and have servers dedicated to a role/function.

"We do not support combining the AD DS role and the failover cluster feature in Windows Server 2012.  This behavior is by design.

Although we do not recommend this, you can enable domain controllers as a cluster node in Windows Server versions earlier than Windows Server 2012. However, starting with Windows Server 2012, we no longer support this configuration. "

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2795523